# Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy, no access to back-end

Tags: reactjs, cors, aws-amplify

When trying to make either a GET or POST request to an API, I get this error: submitRequest:1 Access to fetch at 'API_END_POINT' from origin 'ORIGIN' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

However the API is completely out of my control, I have no access to it whatsoever. Also the issue happens only after I deploy my react app using AWS Amplify. If I run it on my local machine there is no issue. Is there any way to fix this on the front-end??

Answer (score 1):

You can try these 4 options:

## Editing your CORS policy

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://api.example.com; script-src 'self'">
```

Replace the `api.example.com` with the API you are trying to request.

## Consult the documentation for the API specifically

Locate and read any documentation provided for the API. Or look through other people's problems, to see if this is a duplicate.

## Use an internal proxy

1. Create `/proxy.conf.json`

```json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://api.example.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

2. Update your package.json

```json
"scripts": {
   "start-proxy": "react-scripts start --proxy 3001 --config ./proxy.conf.json"
}
```

## Use an online CORS proxy service

Use an online CORS proxy service such as [CORS Anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/). I do not recommend using this, but you could try.

You would then use this code wherever you need:

```js
const apiUrl = 'https://api.example.com';
const corsProxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

fetch(`${corsProxyUrl}${apiUrl}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```